# Conditional heap free

Tags: c, malloc, conditional-statements, free

So, i have this situation. A termination handler and some pointer to struct previously alloc'd on heap.

What i want to do is to use the handler to selectively free them: for each pointer if the correspondent struct is alloc'd has to be free. I use some integer (1 pointer -> 1 int) to control every pointer status (alloc'd or free) and determine if the handler has to frees.

Here's the code

```
/*HEAP STATUS GLOBAL VARIABLES (1 => free required)*/
int free_addrinfo, free_up_rcvd, free_rc_rcvd, free_rc_rspn;

/*HEAP POINTERS*/
struct addrinfo *result;
USR_PSW *up_rcvd;
TBOOK_RECORD *rc_rcvd, *rc_rspn; 

void termination_handler(){
    close(sock_ds);
    close(acc_sock_ds);
    if(free_addrinfo) freeaddrinfo(result);
    if(free_up_rcvd) free(up_rcvd);
    if(free_rc_rcvd) free(rc_rcvd);
    if(free_rc_rspn) free(rc_rspn);
   _exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

Is there a smarter solution? Thank you all in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would just set the variables to NULL on initialization and reset them to NULL again when they are freed. No reason to keep a separate indicator that a pointer is initialized when you already have a natural one.

Actually, in reality, I would attempt write the code in such a way that there's never any doubt about when pointers need to be freed. But when impossible a NULL check is good enough.

Comment: Should I set it manually or `free` leads itself to sets NULL on the pointer?   `{ /*...*/ free(usr_rec); usr_rec = NULL; /*...*/} `

Comment: However the termination_handler can starts at any time. I can't manage that in any other way!

Comment: You have to, of course, set the pointers to `NULL` after calling `free`.

Comment: Ok, now it seems to be more elegant! Thanks!

Comment: Don't really even need to check for NULL.  free(NULL) is guaranteed to do nothing by the C standard, so just free them all, whether they've been allocated or not.

Comment: @LeeDanielCrocker Not for valgrind ;).